# Cannot read property '<<functionName>>' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object, methods, undefined

I have created JavaScript to add on one of the page for Gantt Chart to scroll. My script is as below:

```
<script>SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ScrollToToday,'jsgrid.js');

function ScrollToToday(){

setTimeout(function(){

$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid.ScrollGanttToDate(new Date());

}, 1000);

}
</script>
```

The script is not doing anything. When I debugged the code and in the browser console, added the line `$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid.` I found the functions attached to the `jsgrid` object. But when add the line in the browser console, `$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid.ScrollGanttToDate(new Date());` it is showing me an error `Cannot read property 'ScrollGanttToDate' of undefined`.

[image]

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsGrid, but my guess is that it needs to be `jsgrid()`, rather than `jsgrid`.

Comment: I tried `$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid().ScrollGanttToDate(new Date());
` now it is showing error `$(...)[0].jsgrid is not a function`

Comment: `$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid === 'undefined'` returns `false`